# Finding max value in the second column of a nested list?

Tags: python, list, nested, element, max

I have a list like this:

```
alkaline_earth_values = [['beryllium',  4], 
                         ['magnesium', 12],
                         ['calcium',   20],
                         ['strontium', 38], 
                         ['barium',    56], 
                         ['radium',    88]]
```

If I simply use the `max(list)` method, it will return the answer `'strontium'`, which would be correct if I was trying to find the max *name*, however I'm trying to return the element whose integer is highest.

Comment: The answers here are perfectly good, but it may also be worth checking out [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14884220/search-the-biggest-number-of-one-column-in-a-list-of-list-python#14884336), which was closed as being a duplicate of this one but nevertheless has some useful answers that are not the same as these.

Comment: `max(alkaline_earth_values)` actually returns `['strontium', 38]`, so it's giving you both the name and value _pair_ with the maximum value.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
max(alkaline_earth_values, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

The reason this works is because the *key* argument of the *max* function specifies a function that is called when *max* wants to know the value by which the maximum element will be searched. *max* will call that function for each element in the sequence. And `lambda x: x[1]` creates a small function which takes in a list and returns the first (counting starts from zero) element. So

```
k = lambda x: x[1]
```

is the same as saying

```
def k(l):
  return l[1]
```

but shorter and nice to use in situations like this.

Comment: Would you mind explaining in laymen's terms what this is doing. I think I understand that the x: x[1] defines the position, because if I substitute in 0 for 1 it returns the correct max string value. But, however I do not completely understand the point of key and lambda despite looking at the Python library.

Comment: key is a keyword argument to the max() builtin function. The key argument should be a callable (function, lambda, etc.) that given an element of the iterable returns a value for use in comparison. The "lambda x: x[1]" creates an anonymous function (lambda) that returns the second element of something that supports the Python slice notation.

Comment: So if I had another level of nesting in a list like 

alkaline_earth_values = [['beryllium', 4,['a' ,1]],['magnesium', 12, ['b',2]],['calcium', 20,['c', 3]],['strontium', 38 ['d', 4]],['barium', 56['e', 5]], ['radium', 88['f', 1]]]

Would I do max(alkaline_earth_metals, key = lambda x:x[4] in order to sort by the triple nested integer?

Comment: You mean by the values 1,2,3,4,5,1? In that case you would do: key=lambda x: x[2][1]. Because you would first be taking the 2nd element of ['beryllium', 4, [a, 1]] which would be [a, 1]. And then you would continue by taking the 1st element of that list, which would be 1.

Comment: or would it be
print(max(alkaline_earth_metals, key=lambda x: x[2][1]))

Comment: I've been working with a team who only recently switched to Python and I saw how easy it is to get confused by using max() with nested sequences. I ended up writing a tutorial to do a bit of a deep dive into how the default sorting behavior can be modified, maybe this helps someone out: https://dbader.org/blog/python-min-max-and-nested-lists

Comment: If multiple lists have the same value as an element. How would `lambda` or `itemgetter` get them?

Answer (score 8):

Use the `key` argument.

```
max(alk..., key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: If multiple lists have the same value as an element. How would `lambda`  print the duplications out?

Comment: @user977828 it requires a second iteration, e.g. `m = max(alkaline_earth_values, key=operator.itemgetter(1)); [item for item in alkaline_earth_values if item[1] == m[1]]`

Answer (score 0):

it is rather tricky to assume that an item in a list is actually still a number. If the numbers have become strings, the `max()` will return the 'value' with the highest first number:

```
alkaline_earth_values = [['beryllium', '9'], ['magnesium', '12'],['calcium', '20'],
                         ['strontium', '38'], ['barium', '56'], ['radium', '88']]
max(alkaline_earth_values, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

returns `['beryllium', '9']`

```
max(alkaline_earth_values, key=lambda x: float(x[1]))
```

will do the trick, when you are sure it will be a number

Comment: If multiple lists have the same value as an element. How would `itemgetter`  print the duplication out?

Answer (score 0):

For high speed consider pandas or numpy:

```
Import pandas as pd
alkaline_earth_values = [['beryllium', 4], ['magnesium', 12],['calcium', 20],
                     ['strontium', 38], ['barium', 56], ['radium', 88]]
pd.DataFrame(alkaline_earth_values)[1].max()
```

Comment: If multiple lists have the same value as an element. How would pandas  print the duplication out?

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your list of lists to a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and the call the `.most_common()` method. This easily allow you to find the maximum or top n values:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(dict(alkaline_earth_values)).most_common(1)
[('radium', 88)]
>>> Counter(dict(alkaline_earth_values)).most_common(3)
[('radium', 88), ('barium', 56), ('strontium', 38)]
```