# max second element in tuples python

Tags: python, list, tuples

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting or Finding Max Value by the second element in a nested list. Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800419/sorting-or-finding-max-value-by-the-second-element-in-a-nested-list-python)

I've written a program that gives me a list of tuples. I need to grab the tuple with with the max number in the second value.

```
    (840, 32), (841, 3), (842, 4), (843, 4), (844, 6), (845, 6), (846, 12), (847, 6), (848, 10), (849, 4), ..snip...
```

I need to get back (840,32) because 32 is the highest second number in the tuple. How can I achieve this? I've tried a variety of ways but keep getting stuck here is the complete code:

```
    D = {}
    def divisor(n):
        global D
        L = []
        for i in range(1,n+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            L.append(i)
            D[n] = len(L)

    for j in range(1001):
        divisor(j)


    print(D.items())
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) with `lambda`:

```
In [22]: lis=[(840, 32), (841, 3), (842, 4), (843, 4), (844, 6), (845, 6), (846, 12), (847, 6), (848, 10), (849, 4)]

In [23]: max(lis, key=lambda x:x[1])
Out[23]: (840, 32)
```

or [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
In [24]: import operator 

In [25]: max(lis, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
Out[25]: (840, 32)
```

Comment: note that the operator.itemgetter is preferred over lambda for this kind of key function

Comment: @cravoori totally agree,I always forget to use that.( coz lambda is straight forward doesn't requires  importing any library)