# Get max value in a two value list Python

Tags: python

I have a list which has two values 
(name, number) as shown below:

```
lst = [['ABC', 1.4976557902646848], ['LMN', 1.946130694688788], ['QRS', 3.0039607941124085]]
```

I want to get the name value of the maximum number in this list. In this example it will be 'QRS'

Comment: Don't name your list `list`. It'll override the built-in type.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039192/max-second-element-in-tuples-python might be a closer dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `max` built-in function with `key` kwarg. Refer to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#max) of `max` for more details.

It will return the sublist that has the max number, from which we take the first element (the "name").

```
li = [['ABC', 1.4976557902646848], ['LMN', 1.946130694688788], ['QRS', 3.0039607941124085]]

print(max(li, key=lambda x: x[1])[0])
# QRS
```

You can use `itemgetter` instead of defining the lambda:

```
from operator import itemgetter

li = [['ABC', 1.4976557902646848], ['LMN', 1.946130694688788], ['QRS', 3.0039607941124085]]

print(max(li, key=itemgetter(1))[0])
# QRS
```