# search the biggest number of one column in a list of list

Tags: python, list, max

I have an list of list, `list = [(1,2,5), (2,8,7),(3,6,9)]`, and I want to find the biggest number of the third column, so I tried:

```
zipped = zip(*list)
print max(zipped[2])
```

But it does not show the biggest number. Anyone know why and a solution?

Comment: What does it show instead?

Comment: That is a list of tuples to be clear... And dont name your list `list` or you will be confused when you type `list((1,2,3))`

Comment: The only chance for that not work is that you're on Py3k and zip is an iterator.

Comment: You cannot change a question like that. Create another

Comment: @trivial -- I rolled back your edit.  Don't change the question like that.  If you have a new question, ask a new question (but do a little research first :)

Comment: yes, sorry for that, I never think I can get an answer so so quick!!

Comment: It's worth noting that currently, the answers for this (closed) question contain some tactics that are not in the answers to the older question linked to above.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Works on all newer Pythons:

```
>>> li = [(1,2,5), (2,8,7),(3,6,9)]
>>> max(l[2] for l in li)
9
```

If you have text:

```
>>> li = [('1','2','5'), ('2','8','7'),('3','6','9')]
>>> max(int(l[2]) for l in li)
9
```

And works even if the source is an iterator / generator. This is on Py3.3 where zip returns an iterator:

```
>>> gli=(e for e in li)
>>> max(int(l[2]) for l in gli)
9
>>> max(int(l[2]) for l in zip(*li))
9
```

Comment: Wow ... I have no idea why I didn't write it this way ... (+1) ... I can console myself that it nicely allows OP to get the full tuple with the biggest 3rd item ... But if you just need the item, this is definitely cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

Works for me on python2.7.

```
>>> l = [(1,2,5),(2,8,7),(3,6,9)]
>>> zip(*l)
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 8, 6), (5, 7, 9)]
>>> max(zip(*l)[2])
9
```

---

Another option:

```
max(l,key=lambda x:x[2])[2]
```

or if you prefer `itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
max(l,key=itemgetter(2))[2]
```

This is probably more efficient in terms of memory and it'll work on python3.x where `zip` no longer returns a `list`.

The key here is that it allows you to get the full tuple that is the biggest (biggest determined by the 3rd element) and then you just pull the correct element out of there if you want it.

Comment: Maybe OP's using Py3k and zip returns an iterator

Comment: @JBernardo -- Yeah.  I just thought of that as well... That's why I added that my second version will work on python3.x as well.

Comment: sorry, I find the reason, my list is a list of text and the example I give is a list of number...would you please tell me how to change it?

Comment: @trivial -- `map(int,iterable_of_string)` will return a new list with the strings converted to integers (if possible)