# Max() returns highest list, not number

Tags: list, python-3.x

I have a sample piece of code here:

```
scores = [[1,2,3,6],[1,2,3,9]]

highest = (max(scores[1:3]))
print (highest)
```

I am trying to print the highest number for both of the lists from index 1-3, but it just prints the highest list instead.

```
[1, 2, 3, 9]
```

Before people mark this as duplicate, I have searched other questions ([with this one being the closest related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14884220/search-the-biggest-number-of-one-column-in-a-list-of-list-python#14884336)) but none of them seem to work. Maybe I am missing a small key element.

Comment: Tip: `print(scores[1:3])`

Comment: print [max(a) for a in scores]

Comment: You could use a generator if you want the max out of both lists `print(max(j for i in scores for j in i[1:4]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try applying max to each list as well.

For max of max in each list:

```
print max(max(lst) for lst in scores[1:3])
```

For max per list:

```
print tuple(max(lst) for lst in scores[1:3])
```

Not that indexing starts from `0` so you'll get `(9,)`. To get both:

```
print tuple(max(lst) for lst in scores[0:3])
```

Examples (python 3, so `print` is a function, not a statement):

```
>>> print(max(max(lst) for lst in scores[1:3]))
9
>>> print(tuple(max(lst) for lst in scores[1:3]))
(9,)
>>> print(tuple(max(lst) for lst in scores[0:3]))
(6, 9)
```

Comment: How would I go about doing this if there is a string at the front of the lists? So for example, scores = `[['bob',1,2,3,6],['joe',1,2,3,9]]`

Comment: Yeah, I tried to change the slice to `score_list[1:5]` in order to calculate the highest number for both of the lists but I get `TypeError: unorderable types: int() > str()`

Comment: @TeeKayM Then you want to slice before you take the max. Maybe `print (max(max(lst[1:5]) for lst in scores))`