# How to pick maximum 3 values from a tuple?

Tags: python

I would like to sort a list of tuples, and get the 3 tuples with the biggest values.
The tuples are made like this : ('String', int)

Sample I/O:

Input:

```
wins_list = [("jim", 11), ("pam", 9), ("dwight", 12), ("oscar", 2), ("micheal", 17), ("angela", 3), ("kevin", 1)]
```

Expected Output:

```
["micheal", "dwight", "jim"]
```

Input:

```
wins_list = [("jim", 1), ("pam", 4), ("jan", 10), ("creed", 7), ("micheal", 5), ("meredith", 2), ("phyllis", 28)]
```

Expected Output:

```
["phyllis", "jan", "creed"]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145368/find-the-maximum-value-in-a-list-of-tuples-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding max value in the second column of a nested list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800419/finding-max-value-in-the-second-column-of-a-nested-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def pick_winners(lst):
    lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return [x[0] for x in lst[:3]]
```

A more verbose solution.

Comment: Hi JLeno46.First, I am really thabkful for your answer. I am very new in these codding and pyhton thing and I tried to get appropriate output for first input in my example but I couldn't do that. I wrote your answer like:

Comment: def pick_winners(lst):
    lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return [x[0] for x in lst[:3]]                                                                                                                pick_winners(input()) and give input as wins_list = [("jim", 11), ("pam", 9), ("dwight", 12), ("oscar", 2), ("micheal", 17), ("angela", 3), ("kevin", 1)] but I couldn't solve that. What should I do,thanks for your asnwer and time mate.

Comment: @Serhat Hakan Can Akdaş If you already stored your list in the variable wins_list there's no need to use an input, just call pick_winners(wins_list). You can print the results with print(pick_winners(wins_list))

Comment: But In this question it is said that give an input like wins_list=[blabla...].Then how can I write the variable part of my input in parentheses of pick_winners

Comment: You have to copy/paste your list in your console (or write it), also give a prompt to your input like this: pick_winners(input('insert list here: '))

Answer (score 0):

A one liner from the doc example :
https://docs.python.org/fr/3/howto/sorting.html

```
[t[0] for t in sorted(wins_list, key=lambda winner: winner[1], reverse=True)[0:3]]
```